# alasql- Undefined error

Tags: undefined, alasql

I am pulling data using sharepoint rest service and querying the result data using alasql library. When selecting the field it is returning the data. However, if i use it in group by/sum statement, getting undefined values. For example:

1. Query for one field named zone 
   Query:
   var sud = alasql('SELECT Designation FROM ?',[my_string]);

Result:
(12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{Designation: "Officer - HR"}
1
:
{Designation: "Head - Human Resources"}
2
:
{Designation: "Head - Human Resources"}
3
:
{Designation: "Head - Human Resources"}

2. Query
   var res = alasql('SELECT ROWNUM()  as Rank, Display_x0020_Name AS Employee_Name ,  sum(Give_x0020_Points) AS Points,Designation FROM ? GROUP BY  Display_x0020_Name  ORDER BY  Points DESC ', [my_string]);

Result:
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{Rank: 1, Employee_Name: "D", Points: 70, Designation: undefined}
1
:
{Rank: 2, Employee_Name: "C", Points: 20, Designation: undefined}
2
:
{Rank: 3, Employee_Name: "B", Points: 16, Designation: undefined}
3
:
{Rank: 4, Employee_Name: "A", Points: 10, Designation: undefined}

Designation field does not have any null values. I also want solution if field has null values also.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue got resolved by following by adding all the feilds in Group BY Clause